# Website Menu Not Displayed Properly in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, nav

Here is my website: http://b.countylinemini.com/. The menu is messed up on IE 8 and below. Can't seem to fix it. I have modernizr on there for the shiv. I tried modifying css by enclosing the entire menu in a div to apply style.

Compare that to this screenshot in older IE versions.
https://www.browserstack.com/issue-tracker/945d68fd943803c1db897c7f3fbe455ba7dbfba4/winxp_IE_8.0.jpg

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If anyone has a better solution for the entire nav, I am open to scrapping the whole thing and using different javascript, etc. I noticed it also doesn't work in older apple mobile browsers such as Iphone 4 or lower and Ipad 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is in the CSS.

A quick fix would be to include specific CSS for IE8 and below.
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

The menu unordered list has the style "display:table" and the list items have the style "display:table-cell" and I think this is where your problem is for old IE browsers.

To get it working in older IE, you should be able to set both to "display:block" and just float the list items with "float:left"

Just doing that won't get it looking pixel perfect, but it should function well.

Edit:
If you change menu and you are concerned about ancient browsers, keep it simple - you don't need JavaScript to make a drop down menu. (Also you can do animation in CSS that works for modern browsers and doesn't break old browsers.)  Just hide the sub menu by default and show sub menus when hovering over their parents.

```
ul.menu li.menu-item ul.sub-menu{
display:none;
}
ul.menu li.menu-item:hover ul.sub-menu{
display:block;
}
```

Comment: I added the following code as a imperfect fix, but at least shows the menu somewhat proper. The dropdown submenus are not lining up directly under the main menu item. They are a little off to the side. Also, there is no highlighting when hovering over the menu items for some reason.  
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
 <style>
  ul.sf-menu { 
  display: block;
  }   
  ul.sf-menu li { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }
 </style>
<![endif]--> I'm guessing the rounded corners are also not supported.

Comment: You're right, no rounded corners in IE8 and below. I would look at the issue with your sub menus but I can't seem to get to your site right now (redirects to hosting offers)

Comment: It should be up now. There was issue with the web host.

Comment: For old IE, the submenu needs to have "left:0" - but an inline style is on there "left:auto". Read this on overriding inline styles. https://css-tricks.com/override-inline-styles-with-css/

Comment: I am not able to replicate the problem of "no highlighting when hovering over menu items" - at this point I can't offer any advice.